# How can I amend this particle / solidify glitch?

Tags: modifiers, particles

I'm following a tutorial on how to create a hanging towel and everything was going fine until I had to add a solidify modifier and particles for hair. Can anyone tell me whats going on and how can this be fixed, THANKS!

No Modifiers :

[image]

With Solidify Modifier:

[image]

& With Particles Modifier:

[image]

Comment: possibly du to the scales of your object. Try to apply scale (ctr + A then scale)

Comment: Ok I'll try that :)